# Give sudoers permission to the user form ansible

Tags: linux, ansible

I am trying to give sudo permission to the user `doggy`.
In order to accomplish this I have created a ansible template file that will land `doggy-user.j2` to `/etc/sudoers.d/doggy-user`
Content inside doggy-user.j2 is:

`doggy ALL=NOPASSWD: /bin/ls`

my main.yaml file contains:

```
- name: Allow doggy user minimal sudo rights
  template:
    src: doggy-user.j2
    dest: /etc/sudoers.d/doggy-user
    owner: root
    group: root
    mode: 0440
notify: restart agent
```

but if I apply this change I am getting below error in side the server:

```
    >>> /etc/sudoers.d/doggy-user: syntax error near line 1 <<<
sudo: parse error in /etc/sudoers.d/doggy-user near line 1
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
```

please help here how I can create /etc/sudoers.d/doggy-user in a secure manner with proper sudo rights to the `doggy` user.

Comment: Please add both the .j2 template file /and/ the result on the target system as quoted data to your question. I'm pretty sure the latter will demonstrate what's actually going wrong.

Comment: ... Also, why are you using a template operation at all when you're apparently copying a static file?

Comment: If you don't need the `NOPASSWD` option, it's usually more sensible to add the user to the group `sudo`.

Comment: Your question is confusing: it currently says (paraphrased) "I am trying to allow users to use the `doggy` tool that comes with `ansible`, via `sudo`." The code suggests that you may have meant "I am trying to configure `ansible`, to allow users to run `doggy` via `sudo`." ? Is this correct?

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor It looks like he wants to make an ansible playbook that lets him grant `sudo` access to the `doggy` user.

Comment: @Shadur I know what it looks like. I see it. I have described it. I am asking for clarity from the person that wrote it. Can the author confirm that shadur is correct, and update the question to make it clear.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor From your previous comment it seemed like you thought `doggy` was an app that needed to be run via `sudo`.

Comment: @shadur Did I also mention that the question is confusing. OR that you are not the OP.

Comment: (re-written comment, after correcting: sorry the confusing grammar confused be) Your question is confusing: it currently says (paraphrased) "I am trying to allow user  doggy of ansible, to use sudo." The code suggests that you may have meant "I am trying to configure ansible, to allow user doggy to use sudo." ? Is this correct?

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor Poorly phrased maybe, but not confusing - at least not to me.

Comment: doggy is the app user, and I am using a template because we have multiple templates for other tasks as well so using it will be easier for us.

Comment: yes @shadur "doggy" was an app that needed to be run via sudo

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor corrected my question.

Comment: That template line would give a user named 'doggy' the right to execute `/bin/ls` without being prompted for a password.

Answer (score 2):

It is difficult to add a sudoer file under /etc/sudoers.d/ using ansible template with
user: root
group: root
mode: 0440
The better way is to create the file inside /etc/sudoers.d/ first and then copy the content.

```
- name: Create sudoer file for doggy-user
  file:
    path: "/etc/sudoers.d/doggy-user"
    state: touch
    mode: 0440
    owner: root
    group: root

- name: Add sudoers rules for doggy-user
  copy:
     dest: "/etc/sudoers.d/doggy-user"
     content: |
        doggy-user ALL=NOPASSWD: /bin/ls 
  notify: restart agent
```